# What happens when a serial voting is reversed?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday I received a serial upvoting on many of my questions within a minute or two. Today I saw that the serial voting was reversed (something I had expected to occur). Luckily for me, that happened after I capped so I didn't even see any reputation changes.

I am wondering what are the repercussions to the voter. Does such voter get an immediate notification of the reversal? Are they being listed and warned by moderators? Is there any difference between upvoting and downvoting (in the case where sock puppets are ruled out, of course)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing at all happens by default to the serial voter, there is no notification or automatic consequence. The script is meant to eliminate such patterns without having to involve mods every time. Especially on larger sites this would mean a lot of additional work for the moderators.

If a user repeatedly misuses the voting system by targeting specific users this is a reason for suspension. This is decided on a case-by-case basis.

Serial upvotes by another user are usually well-intended, the user likely saw some good post and then proceeded to look at other posts from the same user. The only action that might be necessary is to explain to the user that one shouldn't target a specific user for votes.

Answer (score 7):

I can't imagine this being anything other than serial upvoting (most likely, well-intentioned). An alternative explanation is that the badge-giving script processed its backlog, but that would affect more than one user.

Presumably the votes will be reversed, i.e., the answers will go back to +9. Will the badges  stay? I guess they will.

[image: nice]  [image: nice]

Comment: Badges aren't removed, at least usually.

Comment: Indeed: the votes were reversed, leaving the badges in place. Lots of [+9 nice answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=12042).